# Grouping and measuring total length of road based on specific attribute in QGIS

Tags: qgis, length, measurements, grouping, summarizing

I have this dataset that describes the cycleways of a city.

[image]

I want to measure the km of cycleway for each type of **highway** (residential, track, unclassified, ecc) and then calculate the percentage of km for each type (eg. if I have a total of 100 km of cycleways, 10 of which are paths, the percentage of paths is 10%)).

*note:* the geometry is a polygon

Comment: you wrote a note: geometry is a polygon, what are you referring to, please explain better.

Answer (score 5):

To get the km of cycleway for each type of highway, use this expression:

```
sum("lunghezza", group_by:="highway")
```

To get the percentage of each highway type, use this expression:

```
sum("lunghezza", group_by:="highway") / sum ("lunghezza")*100
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create a virtual layer with the query:

```
select  row_number() over() as id,
        highway,
        sum(lunghezza) as lunghezza_sum,
        sum(lunghezza)/sum(sum(lunghezza)) over () * 100 as percentage 
        from yourpolygonlayername
        group by highway
```

[image]

Comment: what does the query "row_number() over() as id" do? I'm doing a project with QGIS for my thesis so I need to understand what I'm using. this works perfectly by the way, thank you

Comment: It just adds a row count, 1,2,3, ....   It is to get a unique id column. I think QGIS wants one or it throws an error when trying to create the virtual layer.